# odoo 9 xpath multiple existent field

Tags: xpath, odoo, odoo-9, qweb

I need to change the string of field "name" but this field is multiple existent in the view. So how can i xpath the needed field "name"?
I marked it with --------------------------------->

I tried expr="//group[6]/field[@name='name']" and some other stuff but nothing worked.

```
<record id="view_partner_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">res.partner.form</field>
        <field name="model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="priority" eval="1"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Partners">
            <sheet>
                <div class="oe_button_box" name="button_box">
                    <button name="toggle_active" type="object" groups="base.group_no_one"
                            class="oe_stat_button" icon="fa-archive">
                        <field name="active" widget="boolean_button"
                            options='{"terminology": "archive"}'/>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <field name="image" widget='image' class="oe_avatar" options='{"preview_image": "image_medium", "size": [90, 90]}'/>
                <div class="oe_title">
                    <field name="is_company" invisible="1"/>
                    <field name="company_type" widget="radio"
                        class="oe_edit_only"
                        on_change="on_change_company_type(company_type)"
                        options="{'horizontal': true}"/>
                    <h1>
                        <field name="name" default_focus="1" placeholder="Name" attrs="{'required' : [('type', '=', 'contact')]}"/>
                    </h1>
                    <div class="o_row">
                        <field name="parent_id"
                            placeholder="Company"
                            domain="[('is_company', '=', True)]" context="{'default_is_company': True, 'default_supplier': supplier, 'default_customer': customer}"
                            attrs="{'invisible': [('is_company','=', True),('parent_id', '=', False)]}"
                            on_change="onchange_parent_id(parent_id)"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <group>
                    <group>
                        <field name="type" attrs="{'invisible': [('parent_id','=', False)]}" groups="base.group_no_one"/>
                        <label for="street" string="Address"/>
                        <div class="o_address_format">
                            <div class="oe_edit_only">
                                <button name="open_parent" type="object" string="(edit)" class="oe_link"
                                    attrs="{'invisible': ['|', ('parent_id', '=', False), ('type', '!=', 'contact')]}"/>
                            </div>

                            <field name="street" placeholder="Street..." class="o_address_street"
                                attrs="{'readonly': [('type', '=', 'contact'),('parent_id', '!=', False)]}"/>
                            <field name="street2" placeholder="Street 2..." class="o_address_street"
                                attrs="{'readonly': [('type', '=', 'contact'),('parent_id', '!=', False)]}"/>
                            <field name="city" placeholder="City" class="o_address_city"
                                attrs="{'readonly': [('type', '=', 'contact'),('parent_id', '!=', False)]}"/>
                            <field name="state_id" class="o_address_state" placeholder="State" options='{"no_open": True}' on_change="onchange_state(state_id)"
                                attrs="{'readonly': [('type', '=', 'contact'),('parent_id', '!=', False)]}" context="{'country_id': country_id, 'zip': zip}"/>
                            <field name="zip" placeholder="ZIP" class="o_address_zip"
                                attrs="{'readonly': [('type', '=', 'contact'),('parent_id', '!=', False)]}"/>
                            <field name="country_id" placeholder="Country" class="o_address_country" options='{"no_open": True, "no_create": True}'
                                attrs="{'readonly': [('type', '=', 'contact'),('parent_id', '!=', False)]}"/>
                        </div>
                        <field name="website" widget="url" placeholder="e.g. www.odoo.com"/>
                    </group>
                    <group>
                        <field name="function" placeholder="e.g. Sales Director"
                            attrs="{'invisible': [('is_company','=', True)]}"/>
                        <field name="phone" widget="phone"/>
                        <field name="mobile" widget="phone"/>
                        <field name="fax"/>
                        <field name="user_ids" invisible="1"/>
                        <field name="email" widget="email" attrs="{'required': [('user_ids','!=', [])]}"/>
                        <field name="title" options='{"no_open": True}'
                            attrs="{'invisible': [('is_company', '=', True)]}"/>
                        <field name="lang"/>
                        <field name="category_id" widget="many2many_tags" placeholder="Tags..."/>
                    </group>
                </group>

                <notebook colspan="4">
                    <page string="Contacts &amp; Addresses" autofocus="autofocus">
                        <field name="child_ids" mode="kanban" context="{'default_parent_id': active_id, 'default_street': street, 'default_street2': street2, 'default_city': city, 'default_state_id': state_id, 'default_zip': zip, 'default_country_id': country_id, 'default_supplier': supplier, 'default_customer': customer, 'default_lang': lang,}">
                            <kanban>
                                <field name="color"/>
                                <field name="name"/>
                                <field name="title"/>
                                <field name="type"/>
                                <field name="email"/>
                                <field name="parent_id"/>
                                <field name="is_company"/>
                                <field name="function"/>
                                <field name="phone"/>
                                <field name="street"/>
                                <field name="street2"/>
                                <field name="zip"/>
                                <field name="city"/>
                                <field name="country_id"/>
                                <field name="mobile"/>
                                <field name="fax"/>
                                <field name="state_id"/>
                                <field name="image"/>
                                <field name="lang"/>
                                <templates>
                                    <t t-name="kanban-box">
                                        <t t-set="color" t-value="kanban_color(record.color.raw_value)"/>
                                        <div t-att-class="color + (record.title.raw_value == 1 ? ' oe_kanban_color_alert' : '') + ' oe_kanban_global_click'">
                                            <a t-if="!read_only_mode" type="delete" class="fa fa-times pull-right"/>
                                            <div class="o_kanban_image">
                                                <img t-if="record.image.raw_value" t-att-src="'data:image/png;base64,'+record.image.raw_value"/>
                                                <t t-if="!record.image.raw_value">
                                                    <img t-if="record.type.raw_value === 'delivery'" t-att-src='_s + "/base/static/src/img/truck.png"'/>
                                                    <img t-if="record.type.raw_value === 'invoice'" t-att-src='_s + "/base/static/src/img/money.png"'/>
                                                    <t t-if="record.type.raw_value !== 'invoice' &amp;&amp; record.type.raw_value !== 'delivery'">
                                                        <img t-if="record.is_company.raw_value === true" t-att-src='_s + "/base/static/src/img/company_image.png"'/>
                                                        <img t-if="record.is_company.raw_value === false" t-att-src='_s + "/base/static/src/img/avatar.png"'/>
                                                    </t>
                                                </t>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="oe_kanban_details">
                                                <field name="name"/>
                                                <div t-if="record.function.raw_value"><field name="function"/></div>
                                                <div t-if="record.email.raw_value"><field name="email"/></div>
                                                <div t-if="record.type.raw_value != 'contact'">
                                                    <div>
                                                        <field name="zip"/>
                                                        <field name="city"/>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <field t-if="record.state_id.raw_value" name="state_id"/>
                                                    <field name="country_id"/>
                                                </div>
                                                <div t-if="record.phone.raw_value">Phone: <field name="phone"/></div>
                                                <div t-if="record.mobile.raw_value">Mobile: <field name="mobile"/></div>
                                                <div t-if="record.fax.raw_value">Fax: <field name="fax"/></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </t>
                                </templates>
                            </kanban>
                            <form string="Contact / Address">
                                <sheet>
                                    <field name="type" required="1" widget="radio" options="{'horizontal': true}"/>
                                    <hr/>
                                    <group>
                                        <group attrs="{'invisible': [('type','=', 'contact')]}">
                                            <label for="street" string="Address"/>
                                            <div>
                                                <div class="o_address_format" name="div_address">
                                                    <field name="street" placeholder="Street..." class="o_address_street"/>
                                                    <field name="street2" placeholder="Street 2..." class="o_address_street"/>
                                                    <field name="city" placeholder="City" class="o_address_city"/>
                                                    <field name="state_id" class="o_address_state" placeholder="State" options='{"no_open": True}' on_change="onchange_state(state_id)" context="{'country_id': country_id, 'zip': zip}"/>
                                                    <field name="zip" placeholder="ZIP" class="o_address_zip"/>
                                                    <field name="country_id" placeholder="Country" class="o_address_country" options='{"no_open": True, "no_create": True}'/>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </group>
                                        <group>
              -----------------------------><field name="name" string="Contact Name" attrs="{'required' : [('type', '=', 'contact')]}"/>
                                            <field name="title" placeholder="e.g. Mr."
                                                attrs="{'invisible': [('type','&lt;&gt;', 'contact')]}"/>
                                            <field name="function" placeholder="e.g. Sales Director"
                                                attrs="{'invisible': [('type','&lt;&gt;', 'contact')]}"/>
                                            <field name="email"/>
                                            <field name="phone" widget="phone"/>
                                            <field name="mobile" widget="phone"/>
                                            <field name="comment" placeholder="internal note..."/>
                                        </group>
                                    </group>
                                    <field name="supplier" invisible="True"/>
                                    <field name="customer" invisible="True"/>
                                    <field name="lang" invisible="True"/>
                                </sheet>
                            </form>
                        </field>
                    </page>
                    <page name='internal_notes' string="Internal Notes">
                        <field name="comment" placeholder="Internal note..."/>
                    </page>
                    <page name='sales_purchases' string="Sales &amp; Purchases">
                        <group name="container_row_2">
                            <group string="Sale" name="sale">
                                <field name="customer"/>
                                <field name="user_id" 
                                    context="{'default_groups_ref': ['base.group_partner_manager']}"/>
                            </group>
                            <group string="Purchase" name="purchase">
                                <field name="supplier"/>
                            </group>
                            <group string="Misc">
                                <field name="ref"/>
                                <field name="company_id" groups="base.group_multi_company" options="{'no_create': True}"/>
                            </group>
                        </group>
                    </page>
                </notebook>
            </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't try this but i yhink it will work

```
     //notebook/page/field[@name='child_ids']/form//field[@name='name']
```

Comment: i think you can make it better just play with it more.  you welcome

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using following method.

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='child_ids']/form/sheet/group/group[2]/field[@name='name']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name='string'>Your String</attribute>
</xpath>
```

This may help you.